# Drag and drop small images into a base image

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am new to jQuery and I want to drag some images in to a base image. I want to say that there is a base image and on this image I want to drag and drop some small images. Please suggest some plugins. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Please share some code that you've tried. And also provide some more details on the problem statement.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need any plug in to do this.

Simply using JQueryUI can do this.

Please refer [this](https://jqueryui.com/droppable/#revert/) for help. This is exactly what you want.

Comment: bu I want to drag only in particular image. It should not be drag outside that image.

Comment: Now also I am trying jqueryUI. But it doesn't solve my problem. I think I have to map base image on the basis of which I have to drop small images into it.

Comment: But i think in this only one image can be drag

Comment: I check this but it goes outside the image.